# How to parse a string from one API to other API in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv

I need help in solving the below code. I have an API which gives an output stream as below

```
{
   "country":"Germany",
   "os":"Windows 7",
   "from_mobile":false,
   "base_browser":"Chrome",
   "domain":"furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com",
   "browser":"Chrome 76.0.3809",
   "repeat":true,
   "location":"Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany",
   "base_os":"Windows"
}{
   "country":"Germany",
   "os":"Windows 7",
   "from_mobile":false,
   "base_browser":"Chrome",
   "domain":"furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com",
   "browser":"Chrome 76.0.3809",
   "repeat":true,
   "location":"Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany",
   "base_os":"Windows"
}{
   "country":"Germany",
   "os":"Windows 7",
   "from_mobile":false,
   "base_browser":"Chrome",
   "domain":"furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com",
   "browser":"Chrome 76.0.3809",
   "repeat":true,
   "location":"Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany",
   "base_os":"Windows"
}
```

So can anyone help me how to stream this output as a CSV to another API.

I am calling the API using the axios and want to stream the output to other post API.

Comment: You cannot easily convert from JSON to CSV, because each object may have different properties. Why do you need CSV ? APIs generally uses JSON (or XML in some rare cases)

Comment: if you convert JSON to csv you will have to convert CSV to base 64 for sending data to another API.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot why would he need base64 ? Base64 is mainly used to transport binaries or images, CSV or JSON are neither.

Comment: You can send direct this JSON to another API and store there in CSV. via var json2csv = require("json2csv").parse;

Comment: Why would you send csv you can send JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the first you should update your json, format is wrong at next you can use this module for convert `json to csv`.

```
var jsonToCsv = require('convert-json-to-csv');
var inputJson = [{ "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }, { "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }, { "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }]
var columnDefinitionArray = ['country', 'os', 'from_mobile', 'base_browser', 'domain', 'browser', 'repeat', 'location', 'base_os'];
var arrayOfObjectsCsv = jsonToCsv.convertArrayOfObjects(inputJson, columnDefinitionArray);
console.log(arrayOfObjectsCsv);
```

and with out using the module :

```js
 var inputJson = [{ "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }, { "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }, { "country": "Germany", "os": "Windows 7", "from_mobile": false, "base_browser": "Chrome", "domain": "furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com", "browser": "Chrome 76.0.3809", "repeat": true, "location": "Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany", "base_os": "Windows" }]


console.log(convert(inputJson))
function convert(json) {
    if(json == '')
        return;
    var largestEntry = 0;
    var header;
    for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        if (!Object.keys) {
            Object.keys = function(obj) {
                var keys = [];
                for (var i in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        keys.push(i);
                    }
                }
                return keys;
            };
        }
        if(Object.keys(json[i]).length > largestEntry){
            largestEntry = Object.keys(json[i]).length;
            header = Object.keys(json[i]);
        }
    };
    // Assemble the header
    var convertedjson = "";
    if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach != 'function') {
        Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback){
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            callback.apply(this, [this[i], i, this]);
          }
        };
    }
    header.forEach(function(heading){
        if(convertedjson != "") {
            convertedjson += ",";
        }
        convertedjson += "\"";
        convertedjson += heading
        convertedjson += "\"";
    });
    convertedjson += "\r\n";
    // Iterate through the header for all elements
    json.forEach(function(entry){
        header.forEach(function(heading){
            convertedjson += "\"";
            convertedjson += (entry[heading] || "");
            convertedjson += "\"";
            convertedjson += ",";
        });
        convertedjson = convertedjson.substring(0, convertedjson.length - 1);
        convertedjson += "\r\n";
    });
    return convertedjson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) library

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

const fields = ['country', 'os', 'from_mobile', 'base_browser', 'domain', 'browser', 'repeat', 'location', 'base_os'];
const opts = { fields };

try {

  const parser = new Parser(opts);
  const csv = parser.parse(myData);

  console.log(csv);
} 
catch (err) {

  console.error(err);

}
```